# In Django, given an instance of Model A, how to define a relation between two instances of model B?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

What (I think) I'm trying to achieve is to create a new column in my database (resp. a new field in my model) for model B every time there is a new instance of model A.

To clarify, say I have the following model in Django :

```
class Unit(models.Model):
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

with two instanciations : `Kilograms` and `Volume (m^3)`.

I'm looking to specify the following class:

```
class Object(models.Model):
   object = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   # Field to relate `Volumes` to `Kilograms`, as a float
```

so that I'm able to declare the relation between `Kilograms` and `Volume (m^3)` for each specific object. In a way, I'm trying to declare a float that relates the volume for each kilogram of the object (or vice-versa).

I could use a workaround and add a `FloatField` if I knew `Kilograms` and `Volume` would be the only instances of Unit, but unfortunately, there might be others.

PS: Additional (less important) question: Could I select a default unit, and declare the other ones compared to that default unit. Something like the following:

```
class Object(models.Model):
   object = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   default_unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   # Field to compare unit_1 to default_unit
   # Field to compare unit_2 to default_unit
   # And so on ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, you want to convert between units. Although I haven't fully understood how you will convert kilograms to cubic meters, I'll assume that you also want to convert kilograms to grams.
Your models will be

```
class Unit(models.Model):
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    conversion_factors = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        through='UnitConversion',
        symmetrical=False,
        related_name='converted_units'
    )

class UnitConversion(models.Model):
    from_unit = models.ForeignKey(
        Unit,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='conversion_from'
    )
    to_unit = models.ForeignKey(
        Unit,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='conversion_to'
    )
    conversion_factor = models.FloatField()
```

Therefore you will add kg and g as units,then in your conversion_factor you can add 1000 meaning Ikg==1000g

**In your views.py**

```
#Adding units in database
kg_unit = Unit.objects.create(unit='kg')
g_unit = Unit.objects.create(unit='g')

# Adding the conversion factor for kg to g (1 kg = 1000 g)
conversion = UnitConversion.objects.create(
    from_unit=kg_unit,
    to_unit=g_unit,
    conversion_factor=1000
)
```

Comment: This was not exactly my question (fault is mine). Imagine you have ingredients that can be described using different units : centiliters, grams, spoons, number (of tomatoes). And one would need a conversion from one unit to the other ; a conversion that differ from one ingredient to the other. One centiliter of milk = X grams. One centiliter of floor = Y grams.

I marked the answer as correct as it helped me answer mine anyway, and I feel anyone ending up here would be help as well ! 

Thanks